# setOnClickListener in Android for Two TextViews

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have a Simple Date Picker App in Android and it's working fine when I click on First TextView.
How Can I activate the same Calendar with a second TextView. One TextView shows the Long Date and other shows the Short Date

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mDisplayLongDate;
    TextView mDisplayShortDate;
    CheckBox checkBoxVisibility;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDisplayLongDate = findViewById(R.id.tvLDate);
        mDisplayShortDate = findViewById(R.id.tvSDate);
        //View checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBoxVisibility = findViewById(R.id.checkBox_visibility);
                //boolean isChecked = checkBoxVisibility.isClickable();
        boolean isChecked = checkBoxVisibility.isChecked();
        updateTextVisibility(isChecked);
        checkBoxVisibility.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked1) -> {
            //Step 05 - Updating UI according to the currently changed state
            updateTextVisibility(isChecked1);
        });

        mDisplayLongDate.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

With a CheckBox, the TextView Shows Long Date and Short Date.
I cannot click on the short date to edit the Calendar. How to activate the Calendar in both situation.

```
String dateLong = monthStr + "/" + day + "/" + year;
            String dateShort = monthStr + "/" + day;

            mDisplayLongDate.setText(dateLong);
            mDisplayShortDate.setText(dateShort);
        };
    }
    private void updateTextVisibility(boolean isChecked) // When checking the trigger (checkbox)
    {
        if (isChecked)
        {
            mDisplayShortDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mDisplayLongDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            mDisplayShortDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mDisplayLongDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: did u try using the same calendarand dateTimePicker instance . just invoke it using same way as first textview

Comment: where is your current onClickListener?

Comment: mDisplayLongDate.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();, It's on the Long Date Text View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this type of method and call it where you need .

```
    private void getCal() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int monthStr = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog dPDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedY, int selectedM, int selectedD) {

                    String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH).getMonths();
                    String dateLong = months[selectedM] + "/" + selectedD + "/" + selectedY;
                    String dateShort = months[selectedM] + "/" + selectedD;
                   // String dateLong = (selectedM + 1) + "/" + selectedD + "/" + selectedY;
                    //String dateShort = (selectedM + 1) + "/" + selectedD;
                    mDisplayLongDate.setText(dateLong);
                    mDisplayShortDate.setText(dateShort);

                }
            }, year, monthStr, day);
    dPDialog.show();


}
```

Example class-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mDisplayLongDate;
TextView mDisplayShortDate;
CheckBox checkBoxVisibility;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDisplayLongDate = findViewById(R.id.tvLDate);
    mDisplayShortDate = findViewById(R.id.tvSDate);

    mDisplayLongDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getCal();
        }
    });


    mDisplayShortDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getCal();
        }
    });


}

 private void getCal() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int monthStr = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog dPDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedY, int selectedM, int selectedD) {

                    String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH).getMonths();
                    String dateLong = months[selectedM] + "/" + selectedD + "/" + selectedY;
                    String dateShort = months[selectedM] + "/" + selectedD;
                   // String dateLong = (selectedM + 1) + "/" + selectedD + "/" + selectedY;
                    //String dateShort = (selectedM + 1) + "/" + selectedD;
                    mDisplayLongDate.setText(dateLong);
                    mDisplayShortDate.setText(dateShort);

                }
            }, year, monthStr, day);
    dPDialog.show();


}
  }
```

Comment: Getting a warning message @: "Private field 'mDateSetListener' is never assigned" and "Private method 'updateTextVisibility(boolean)' is never used"

Comment: You can ignore this , or remove access modifier "private" of these.

Comment: I removed private" and still the build failed, not sure if I miss something

Comment: would you please share logcat

Comment: Once I select the date from the calendar, textview doesn't show that date

Comment: Just update the textview inside getCal() , check updated answer I have added few lines.

Comment: Thanks Zahid, This is working fine now. Appreciate your help!!

Comment: How can I get month number to Name, like 1 to January. I tried to use **switch case** option but doesn't seem to work

Comment: use DateFormatSymbols to get that , check updated answer.